# Assign Error when building custom package in R (can't add bindings to locked environment)

Tags: r, devtools, r-package

First question on StackOverflow.

I'm using R to create a package that will run an automated conversion of a imported data set. Then do a bunch of manipulations and graph it.

However, I want this to be as friendly to new users as possible.

I am currently having an issue when using the assign() command.

Here is my Code which is in a .R file inside of \R folder. The goal of this function is to take a dataset, manipulate it, save it for users to see and call without :: (global)

```
    SplitRawconvert = function(dataset,mapname,env = globalenv())
    {


  print("wegotthisfar")

  ContactPosx = -4648
  ContactPosy = 3900
  Contactscale = 9



  if(mapname=="contact" || mapname =="Contact")
  {
    #' saves the converted files to "Contact" specific tag.

    convertedkills = data.frame(dataset[,1], ((dataset[,2]-ContactPosx)/Contactscale), ((dataset[,3]-ContactPosy)/Contactscale))
    names(convertedkills) = c("Side","X","Y")

    converteddeaths = data.frame(dataset[,7], ((dataset[,8]-ContactPosx)/Contactscale), ((dataset[,8]-ContactPosy)/Contactscale))
    names(converteddeaths) = c("Side","X","Y")

    assign(paste("convertedkills",mapname,sep=""),convertedkills,envir=env)
    assign(paste("converteddeaths",mapname,sep=""),converteddeaths,envir=env)

    #' split the deaths and kills by "side"
    splitdatadeaths = split(converteddeaths,converteddeaths[,1])
    splitdatakills = split(convertedkills,convertedkills[,1])


    DS = splitdatadeaths$Security
    DI = splitdatadeaths$Insurgents

    KS = splitdatakills$Security
    KI = splitdatakills$Insurgents


    assign(paste(mapname,"DeathSec",sep=""),DS,envir=env)
    assign(paste(mapname,"DeathIns",sep=""),DI,envir=env)
    assign(paste(mapname,"KillSec",sep=""),KS,envir=env)
    assign(paste(mapname,"KillIns",sep=""),KI,envir=env)
    }
    }`
```

I do know I'm saving to ta global environment this is on purpose so that the converted data can be accessed by the global environment.

I'm new to R package development, but a few days ago (while still using assign) the package would build totally fine.

The error I receive is after running build&check

http://puu.sh/nvXfI/22ddced453.png

(link to image above)

"Error in importIntoEnv(pkgenv, exports, nsenv, exports) : 
  cannot add bindings to a locked environment
Calls: suppressPackageStartupMessages ...  -> load_all -> export_ns -> importIntoEnv
Execution halted"

The specific line of code is the env=globalenv() call in the function title.

Is there a better way to save and store manipulated data sets? I want my users to be able to call the data sets and functions without having to use ::

Comment: You shouldn't be saving to the global environment anyway. A better approach would be to return a list

Comment: Thank you for your reply Hadley!!!

I am in a bit over my head when it comes to making a R package, I will try to restructure the package to not write to global.